Является ли сочетание "итоговый результат" тавтологией?
Является ли сочетание "итоговый результат" / "конечный результат" тавтологией или другого вида ошибкой? Ведь по сути результат это и есть итог чего-либо.

Ничего не вижу тавтологического в этих словосочетаниях, ведь, кроме итогового или конечного результата, может быть и промежуточный результат
